# How to create an array of hashes with an array of items in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having a hard time figuring out how to do this. I have a set of items returned from a where query. Each item belongs to a menu. I'd like to create an array called menus that has as its items the name of the item's menu and then create a sub-array of items but I can't figure this out.

I'd like (assuming "blue" and "red" are names of the menus):

```
  menus:["blue":
          {"items":["ocean","sky"]}],
         "red"  
          {"items":["fire","sunset"]}]
    ]
```

and items will have a belongs_to relationship to get to menu. I tried

```
menus=[]
items.each do |mi|
  menus << mi.menu.name
end
```

but can't get this to work. I'm thinking I need to do a collect but not sure.

Comment: does `menus` is a key of the rest all object `[..]` ?

Comment: What does "can't get this to work" mean? ***How is it not working***? Can you please give us more details? What is the `where` query that you're using to retrieve your items? What do your models look like?

Comment: i tihnk the belongs_to is pretty clear what the relationship is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you indicate as the result you want is *not* a valid array, because array item don't have "names". This is a valid array:

```
[{"items":["ocean","sky"]}, {"items":["fire","sunset"]}]
```

While this is a hash:

```
{"blue":
      {"items":["ocean","sky"]}],
 "red":
      {"items":["fire","sunset"]}]
}
```

To get a hash you can do the following:

```
menus={}
items.each do |mi|
  (menus[mi.menu.name] ||= []) << mi.name
end
```

To get only the array above, you should simply add to the code above:

```
menus.values
```